# How to run a function only one time from within an infinite loop?

Tags: c, function, infinite-loop

I'm writing a game engine in C that can run on multiple older platforms, such as Sega Saturn and PS1. I've come across a small issue, though. The game has a main loop from which all other functions are called. That means it's pretty hard to call a function just one time without there being states involved. So, I need to know the best way to do it. I'll show a brief example of how it's set up:

```
mainloop() //This function repeats forever
{
    myFunc1(); //Therefore, this function also repeats forever.
}

myFunc1() //Subsequent, gameplay related function
{
    if(myThing == 9){  //This thing is gonna equal 9 for quite a while, so that means the fucntion below will also be called like a bunch. But we don't want it to!
        runFuncOnce(); //Run this function only one time
    }
}

runFuncOnce() //I only want this function to do stuff one time until the next time it gets called!
{
    //Some examples of things you'd only want to do one time:
    PlayASound(MySound);
    ResetAnimation(MyAnimation); //Set an animation back to its first frame
    myVariable = 5; //Set this variable to whatever, but only once!
    printf("Hey, you did a thing. Good job! If you're lucky you won't see this text like 8 billion times in a row")
}
```

Granted, you wouldn't want to do these things within the same function, but you get the idea. There are some dumb ways to do this, but I'm trying to do this in the cleanest and fastest way possible. I don't want to talk about the ways I've *done* it, because people will most likely focus on the way I've tried it before, and try to fix that. Give me fresh ideas! Trust me, the ways I've done it before are dumb and slow. That's why I'm here!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/call_once

Comment: `static bool runOnce = runFuncOnce();`

Comment: `bool hasBeenRun = false; if(!hasBeenRun) { runFuncOnce(); hasBeenRun = true; }`

Comment: Your question is asking for opinions on how to write code and Stack Overflow is not a platform for doing that. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static variable.

```
myFunc1() //Subsequent, gameplay related function
{
    static bool runOnlyOnce = false;

    if(myThing == 9) {  //This thing is gonna equal 9 for quite a while, so that means the function below will also be called like a bunch. But we don't want it to!
        if (runOnlyOnce == false) {
            runFuncOnce(); //Run this function only one time
            runOnlyOnce = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The static variable value persists between function calls. So, when next time `myFunc1()` gets called, it finds the value of `runOnlyOnce` variable `true` and will not call `runFunOnce()` again.